# Highchart HighStock Angular 2 Changing PlotOptions Series Compare from Percent to Value

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts

In HighStock trying to add a toggle button for viewing absolute value and Percent Change. However, this.chart.update does not seem to update the charts.

```
saveInstance(chartInstance) {
    this.chart = chartInstance;
    }
  prcentchg(){
    if(this.chart.options.plotOptions.series.compare !== 'percent'){
       this.chart.options.title.text = '====> Percent <===='
        this.chart.options.plotOptions.series.compare = 'percent';
        this.chart.options.tooltip.pointFormat = '<span style="color:
     {series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.change}%)<br/>'
        this.chart.update(this.chart.options)
        console.log(this.chart.series[0])
    }else {
        this.chart.options.title.text = '====> Absolute Value <===='
        this.chart.options.plotOptions.series.compare = 'value';
        this.chart.options.tooltip.pointFormat = '<span style="color:{series.color}">{point.y}</span>'
        this.chart.update(this.chart.options)
        console.log(this.chart)
    }
```

**See Plunker Link** :  [PLUNKER LINK](https://plnkr.co/edit/tcnPxqsULeSn8M1oUQjM?p=preview)

Comment: Take a look at  http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/Axis.setCompare

Comment: Working correctly now, or still having problems?

Comment: @BarbaraLaird Working beautifully, Thank you. Please see Updated Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/tcnPxqsULeSn8M1oUQjM?p=preview .Also, I've added a for-loop to update the tooltips.